# El caso de la pregunta: Enviar datos al servidor mediante Ajax usando Promesas de JavaScript

Tags: discusión, pregunta-específica

Formulé esta pregunta bajo otro título hace un tiempo, y la misma fue marcada como duplicada justamente.

A raíz de eso modifiqué el título y el sentido de la pregunta, la cual está planteada así actualmente:

[Enviar datos al servidor mediante Ajax usando Promesas de JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/79849/29967)

Me parece una pregunta interesante, dado que el tema de Promises es nuevo. He probado un código que hace llamadas a Ajax usando Promises y me gustaría incluirlo como respuesta.

**¿Sería mejor eliminar esa pregunta y crear otra nueva o bien solicitar la re-apertura de la misma?**

Uno de los problemas que veo es que la pregunta tiene respuestas orientadas al planteamiento primero, y eso dejaría dichas respuestas desfasadas. Una de ellas es bastante buena, y podría ser útil en la pregunta [¿Cómo realizar una llamada AJAX sin bibliotecas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/25798/29967), se lo he indicado a su autor para que la mueva a esa pregunta, pero eso no ha ocurrido.

**¿Cómo sería mejor proceder en este caso?**

Comment: La regla general seria: Si hay algo util, no lo pierdas

Comment: Haber cambiado el sentido de la pregunta, ¿no va en contra del trabajo realizado por quien te respondió? Y, por otro lado, ¿por qué no responder sobre la pregunta sobre la cual fue marcada como duplicada, en vez de crear una nueva?

Comment: Coincido con @Mariano. Si recibió buenas respuestas, cambiar el enunciado y dejarlas obsoletas es hacerles una faena; mejor formularlo en una pregunta nueva. Recordemos que el hecho de que te marquen una pregunta como duplicada no es algo intrínsecamente malo, simplemente marca otro punto de entrada de las visitas hacia una pregunta del mismo tipo.

Comment: Yo coincido tambien con los anteriores. Si consideras que el duplicado no incluye esta nueva información,creo que es mejor que realices una nueva pregunta autorespondida, y si se encaja en el duplicado puedes añadir tu respuesta ahi.

Comment: De acuerdo a lo que han comentado, concluyo que se podría hacer lo siguiente: 1. **Revertir** la actual pregunta marcada como duplicada a su **estado original**, cuyo título era: _Enviar datos al servidor mediante Ajax sin usar librerías tales como jQuery_, dejando en ella las respuestas ya dadas, que son una importante contribución al tema. 2. **Crear una nueva pregunta-respuesta** titulada: _Enviar datos al servidor mediante Ajax usando Promesas de JavaScript_ ¿Les parece una solución correcta?

Comment: @A.Cedano a mí me parece fenomenal. Incluso después puedes añadir una línea en la pregunta _sin usar jQuery_ referenciando la pregunta que crees referente a _usando Promises_.

Comment: No entendí ... @fedorqui

Comment: @A.Cedano disculpa, me refiero a que luego puedes poner un enlace de una pregunta a otra.

Comment: Ahora sí. Entendido y gracias @fedorqui Eso será hecho. Saludos.

Comment: Dado que ya procediste así, sugiero crear una respuesta explicándolo. Me alegra ver cómo gestionaste esta situación, A. Cedano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo a lo que han comentado, se ha hecho lo siguiente:

1. Revertir la actual pregunta marcada como duplicada a su estado original, cuyo título era y seguirá siendo desde ahora: **[Enviar datos al servidor mediante Ajax sin usar librerías tales como jQuery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/79849/29967)**, dejando en ella las respuestas ya dadas, que son una importante contribución al tema.
2. Crear una nueva pregunta-respuesta titulada: **[Enviar datos al servidor mediante Ajax usando Promesas de JavaScript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/86989/29967)**

De este modo se salvan las dos preguntas y sus respuestas.